# Databinding Textbox to Form.Text (title)

Tags: c#, winforms, data-binding, textbox, title

I'm trying to bind a `Textbox.Text` to `Form.Text` (which sets the title of the form).
The binding itself works. But, the title isn't updated until I move the entire form.

How can I achieve `Form.Text` being updated without moving the form? I'd like `Form.Text` being updated directly when I type something in the Textbox.

Edit; I set the title of the Form in a TextChanged event which is fired by a ToolStripTextbox:

```
public partial class ProjectForm : Form
{
   public ProjectForm()
   {
       // my code contains all sorts of code here, 
       // but nothing that has something to do with the text.
   }
}

private void projectName_TextChanged_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.Text = projectName.TextBox.Text;
}
```

And the Databinding version:

```
public partial class ProjectForm : Form
{
   public ProjectForm()
   {
       this.projectName.TextBox.DataBindings.Add("Text", this, "Text", true, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnValidation);
   }
}
```

Edit 2: I see I forgot to mention something. Don't know if it adds anything, but my apllication is a MDI application. The part of the title that changes is:

```
ApplicationName [THIS CHANGES, BUT ONLY AFTER MOVING/RESIZING]
```

Comment: Really strange. I've never observed any repaint problems when setting the Form.Text property directly. Can you share some code snippet with us?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Classic problem, you're not updating the existing form's Text property but a new one that is not visible.  Call the Show() method after you change the Text.

[Source](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winforms/thread/b525de56-5c74-4db6-9cc4-31a0dbffa857)

You can also try invalidating your form in the TextChanged event so it will force a re-paint.

**Edit 1:** This [StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1347734/mdi-window-list-not-updating-child-title-bar-texts) may provide an answer for you since you are a MDI application

**Edit 2:** It could be that this operation is not thread-safe and therefore the UI thread is blocking. Therefore, you need to **invoke** another function in order to cause it to update. I had a similar problem with StatusBar Labels a while back. Here is some example code if you do not know how to use delegates:

```
public delegate void updateFormTextD(string text);

private void formText(string text)
{
     this.Text = text;
}

private void updateFormText(string text)
{
     Invoke(new updateFormTextD(formText), text);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What about using the TextChanged event of the TextBox, like this:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Text = this.textBox1.Text;
    }
}
```

Comment: This results in the same behavior as described in my Question. So the Text is updated when I move/resize the form.

Comment: Don't know what to tell you then, I created a simple application with just that code and I had no problems. It seems to be a case of: "Hey, it works on my machine." Sorry, I can't help you any further...

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem that almost freaks me out. Eventually I found that my form title update request by "this.text = " was blocked by the method "WndProc(ref Message message)". At the end of WndProc method I added "base.WndProc(ref message)", which passes along all messages to the base also. After that I could update successfully my form title by "this.text = ".

Therefore, I suggest you to look for a method that blocking your form title for being updated.

Answer (score 0):

None of the traditional items worked (invalidate & refresh); nor was I able to readily determine where the message might have been blocked. However, sleeping the thread took care of this.

```
fForm1->Text = Title;

Thread::Sleep(0); //Allow release for title to update
```